# python if statement printing more than it should

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

i am working on building a model and trying to get the rgb value of the pixels in a specific image  before i move into labeling the data
the if statement below printing right but the value should be incremented only by 1 not to keep on infinity incrementing .
can you help to know the reason?

```
for image in train_data[10:11]:
  img = Image.open(image)
  rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
  for x in range(rgb_im.size[0]):
    for y in range(rgb_im.size[1]):
      r1, g1, b1 = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
      if (r1,g1,b1) == color and x == 445 and y == 60:
        countPositive += 1
        print(countPositive)
      else:
        countNegative += 1
        print(countNegative)
```

[print screen to the output from google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgKyM.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "...not keep looping". Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can use `break` if you mean what I think you mean.

Comment: @glibdud sorry fixed it, i meant it's infinity increment

Comment: @Vassilios tried it but still not working

Comment: I don't see any way for that block of code to produce an infinite loop. Is it just happening more times than you expect? You might need to lay out a little more clearly what exactly you expect the result to be, and what you're seeing instead.

Comment: Move the `print` statements to after the `for` loops?

Comment: Based on this code, you're going to print one number for each pixel in each image in `train_data[10:11]`. Not infinite, just a lot. What number do you actually mean to increment and print?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image? 40,000 pixels is a very small image.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp did it and it's working, thank you, how to mark it as an answer?

Comment: This code looks like it is doing what you want, I think you may be underestimating how many pixels you have. For a reference point, running this on an image from a consumer camer like the Nikon D5300 you should expect `CountNegative` to reach values around 24,000,000, while your screenshot only shows 40,000.

Comment: Wael, you can't do that to a comment, but if Johnny wants to rewrite his post as an answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running on every pixel in the image and increment countNegative.
You should expect to large number as the size of your image (-1 if the condition is true)